# Where do I find Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager to add as reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wanted to add the following refernces on my console application in VS2013 installed with VS2013 SDK

1. Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation

I'm not able to find a reference in the Reference Manager.

The below image shows that I can find Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.12.0 of VS2013 SDK

[image: Reference can be found here]

The below image shows that the above mentioned ExtensionManager refernces cannot be found.

[image: Reference cannot be found]

Comment: Google is a wonderful thing: http://blog.ninlabs.com/2011/04/auto-update-visual-studio-extensions/

Comment: The link that you provided was really useful, Thank you and I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see either of them in the "Reference Manager" either, but on my machine they're in the GAC:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation\v4.0_11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a

As well as in the VS2013 install directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

If you're considering using this in a production environment, note that the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.extensionmanager.aspx) states:

> Although this API supports the Extension Manager infrastructure, we recommend that you do not use it because it is subject to change.

Comment: What could be worst case scenario if I'm using it. My intention is to install Extensions externally from code into VS2013