# How can I programmatically enable Visual Studio extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I need to enable a specific and already installed Visual Studio extension per code or command line.
I already found the Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager API, but it seems depracated and not very safe to use it in production, as also stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294046/where-do-i-find-microsoft-visualstudio-extensionmanager-to-add-as-reference).
Additionally I ran ProcessMonitor to find out what happens when enabling an extension in VS, but did not find any helpful operations.

Maybe there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: I also didn’t find any [alternative dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=ExtensionManager), you may have to use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll` API, and yes, it is not recommended to use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.